# My navigationbar doesn't show a back button if the previous view controller has no title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, title

How do i make it show the back button, with the title "Back"? It shows perfectly well if the previous view controller has a title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the backBarButtonItem property of the previous viewController. So if you are have one viewcontroller "A" and you push a viewController "B". The back button will be the button backBarButtonItem on the "A" view controller.

Comment: I just tried this, but `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";` does nothing.

Comment: But try the more formal method, setTitle: on the backBarButtonItem. It should work.

Comment: That also doesn't change anything.

Comment: You may have to specify a new button instance. I would check to see if self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem is nil or not. It is possible that it defaults to nil and automatically makes the default button if it isn't set when it goes to draw the navigationBar.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution is in viewDidLoad of the view that is about to push a new one, do the following:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
[backBarButton release]
```

Works perfectly, no questions asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to set the title before pushing the new view controller. For example:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [self setTitle:@"back"];
  // Push new view controller...
}
```

and then set it back to @"" in your `-viewWillAppear`.